# Nativescript - view dimensions during the loaded event

Tags: nativescript

Shouldn't the dimensions for views be set during the LOADED page event callback?

The values don't seem to be set. If I navigate to a different page and then back - the values are then set.

This is iOS - pretty sure same under Android.

Comment: Could you provide some more info about your problem? In case you want to get the screen width and height, you could use platform modules. For example: `import platform = require("platform");` `var currentPageWidth = platform.screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs` `var currentPageHeight = platform.screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs`

Comment: @NikolayTsonev that would only work for the current screen however, and not for individual views.

As a workaround you can try delaying reading of the dimensions by a couple milliseconds. A setTimeout of about 40ms is normally sufficient for the view dimensions to be fed. It's hacky, but it does the job.